# Detect if my app is uninstalled

Tags: android, uninstallation

Is it possible to have a code that detect if my app has been uninstalled and upon uninstalling, all the relevant folders that my app has created will be deleted automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: These guys managed to do it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl

Comment: That's technically a correct answer (even though I didn't see where they say they managed to do that on the link you provided), but the followup question is: how did they do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your solutions! At least I know now my app cannot detect an uninstall. 
But I have solved the problem of removing all the relevant folders that my app has created by placing relevant folders in: `context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()`  
Everytime Android uninstall ur app, it will delete everything in the `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.yourapp.com` folder. 
`context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();` put ur folders inside the `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.yourapp.com` folder.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding being able to detect the Uninstallation, I'm afraid its not possible.

Whenever an application package is removed(App is Uninstalled), **ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED** intent will be sent out to all receivers **EXCEPT** for your own.

From the docs:-

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed
>   from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The
>   package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.

This is [confirmed here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).

Answer (score 1):

No dear you cant check that your application is going to uninstall.

But you can create your folder in your cache dir so that when your application will be deleted all folders and files automatically will be deleted.

Please check it. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html