# Calling webservice when uninstalling app

Tags: android, lifecycle

I have an app with webservice. When i uninstall my app from my phone i want to call webservice just before uninstallation completes.How can i do it?

I have searched but couldn't get it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can't make your application aware that it is being uninstalled.. have a read; [Detect if my app is uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286678/detect-if-my-app-is-uninstalled)

As for your problem, you could keep a record of active users in your web service. Then after a period of inactivity, assume these applications have been uninstalled.